# bootstrap Stack model scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know why that when I open "test-modal", It can be scroll in the modal.
 Then click "Launch Modal 2" and close it, "test-modal" cannot scroll and It will scroll in the background.
I want to know that how can I scroll in "test-modal" after I close the "test-modal-2"?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Stack Bootstrap modals nicely</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal">Show Modal</button>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <h1>
        <div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" data-modal-index="1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                 <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal-2">Launch Modal 2</button>
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->


    <div class="modal fade" id="test-modal-2" data-modal-index="2">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are two or more modals are opened,after close the upper modal, The class .modal-open assigned to body will be removed.

The focus will go to body instead of previous modal.

In order to change the focus to previous modal, you need to add the class .modal-open to body again.

The code below add class to the body when #test-modal-2 is closed.

```js
$('#test-modal-2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("body").addClass("modal-open");
})
```